# Numpy emoji board flips when I send it on Instagrams dm , but it's correct on vs code terminal

Tags: python, numpy, selenium

I want to send a numpy board made up of emoji on Instagram dm but for some reason it flips when I send it. Nonetheless it is printed correctly in the vs code terminal.

### here is the output in the terminal:

```
0️⃣   1️⃣2️⃣3️⃣4️⃣5️⃣6️⃣7️⃣
1️⃣   
2️⃣   
3️⃣   
4️⃣   
5️⃣    
6️⃣
```

### Here is the message send on Instagram dm:

```
0️⃣ 1️⃣2️⃣3️⃣4️⃣5️⃣6️⃣7️⃣1️⃣ 
2️⃣ 
3️⃣ 
4️⃣ 
5️⃣ 
6️⃣
```

### ***Here is where I suspect an error***

this in java and I add it because you can not send emojis using chrome driver

```
JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
  var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
  elm.value += txt;
  elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  """
```

### **Here is my code**

```
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\saksh\\Desktop\\codeing\\Projects\\Connect 4\\chrome profiles\\chrome profile - 1")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options =  options , executable_path = r"C:\Users\saksh\Desktop\codeing\imported items\chromedriver v-90.exe")


ROW_COUNT = 6
COLUMN_COUNT = 7


def create_board():
    board = np.zeros((ROW_COUNT, COLUMN_COUNT))

    return board


board = create_board()



# manually go u any instagram dm 

print("manually go u any instagram dm , and press enter") 

input("press enter !!")


JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
  var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
  elm.value += txt;
  elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  """

def send_board(board):
    board = str(repr(np.flip(board, 0)))
    board  = board.replace("0", "")
    board = board.replace("1", "")
    board =  board.replace("2", "⚫")
    board = repr(board)
    board = board.replace("'array([[" , "")
    board = board.replace("]])'" , "" ) 
    board = board.replace("," , "")
    board = board.replace("[" , "")
    board = board.replace("]" , "")
    board = board.replace("\\n" , "")
    board = board.replace(" " , "")
    board = board.replace("." , "")
    n = int(len(board)/6)
    out = [(board[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(board), n)]
    out.insert( 0 , '1️⃣2️⃣3️⃣4️⃣5️⃣6️⃣7️⃣')
    o = 0
    number_emoji = [ '0️⃣','1️⃣','2️⃣','3️⃣','4️⃣','5️⃣','6️⃣','7️⃣','8️⃣','9️⃣'  ]

    for i in out:
        i =  str(o) + i 
        io = i.replace( str(o) , number_emoji[o] + "   ")
        print(io)
        message_box = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".ItkAi > textarea:nth-child(1)")
        browser.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, message_box, io)
        message_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER, Keys.SHIFT)
        o += 1

    message_box.send_keys("  ")
    message_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    
board  = send_board(board)
```

I am using python 3.9.5 with the selenium package in its latest version.

Comment: Why is the "one" skipped when you send it via Instagram dm? I see 0 then 2

Comment: @sehan2 I see a 1. See the end of the first line.

Comment: ah ok, then you probably made an error with the line break I presume